# Calling addEventListener or using onscroll handler?

Tags: javascript

I have two approaches making my element scroll on the window which both work but what are the two differences and which one is a better approach. Thanks!

First approach

```
window.onscroll = function() {rotate()};

function rotate(){
}
```

Second approach

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', rotate);

function rotate(){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add more that one handler with `addEventListener`, where as assigning `onscroll` you can only have one handler at a time.

For example if you have two sections of code that need to listen to a scroll event, they can't both set `onscroll`, as the first one will be overwritten. So instead both can call `addEventListener` and each receive the event.

Answer (score 0):

**addEventListener:**
The addEventListener() method attaches an event handler to the specified element.
It handles more than one Event.
For example:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
});
```

The **onscroll** event occurs when an element's scrollbar is being scrolled.
it handles only one event.
    
onscroll work try this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onscroll